# php session pass with setcookie and unset

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, unset

i have a strange problem, when i use `setcookie` in PHP with session, while my browser is open, everything work fine, but when I close it, then I can't pass `$_SESSION` from page to another page!
in login page I have:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
$life=2592000;//1 month
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$life);
header("location:administrator/");
die();
```

I used `session_start();` in every page on top of them, also I used this code for logout:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']);
unset($_SESSION['pass']);
session_destroy();
header("location:../");
```

an important note is when I checked browser cookies, before closing browser there are tow cookie and their contents value is exactly same like each other, one expire at the end of session but another expire one month latter, which I like to be, but then I close browser and return back, there are tow cookie but with different values! which I think case problem and session variables don't pass from page to page.

Comment: You realize that you lose the `$_SESSION` when you close your browser, right?

Comment: when i close browser session lost and cookie not work! but i can't login again because i cant pass $_SESSION from check page to administrator. note: when i delete cookie, login work!

Comment: this is my logout page! i must destroy it then redirect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem mentioned by @Matt (you may need some custom mechanism to restore or reinstantinate session using cookies), keep in mind that using mod_rewrite or actual directories messes with cookies path! To make sure the cookie is available when and where you need it, add additional parameter `/` ([PHP setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), $path parameter)

Comment: glad to hear that. But be aware that session files are usually stored in temp dir and deleted after few hours (depending on server config). Therefore take @Matt advice and reinstantinate session using value stored in cookie (probably some pointer to db record)